# Title column in list

Tags: 2010, list-view, custom-list, title-column

I am having a list with few columns and one is Title (linked to item with menu) and other is Title. When I am trying to set up the view I can see that the Title column in the view selection getting blurred and in the page only Title(linked to item with menu) is showing . Please find the image below.
[image]

Comment: What's the list type?

Comment: Hi Qassas this is a custom list from OOTB.

Comment: What's the SharePoint version?

Comment: SharePoint 2010

Comment: Do you use any content type ? do you count the items by title column in total section in your view?

Comment: It has Item as content type.No count on items using this column.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/63567/discussion-between-splearner-and-m-qassas).

Comment: @SPLearner  Refer this link. This may be helpful for you -- https://expectedexception.wordpress.com/2011/03/31/cant-remove-columns-form-a-sharepoint-view-checkboxes-disabled/

Comment: Hi Rohit I have seen that link, but I am looking to uncheck the column and use it. When i create a new view the column is still grayed out for me to uncheck. any other suggestions?